# Good way to automate user login and keep the user information in Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, implicit

First of all, I'm still a newbie in scala, so this question can seem pretty basic, or maybe my approach is wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to do this:

I've integrated **Oauth2** authentication into my project and now I'm trying to automatize the login, so instead of writting in every function the:

```
Action.async { implicit request =>
        authorize(new OauthDataHandler()) { authInfo =>
```

code, I want to use my custom Action and do:

```
def index = OAuth2Action { implicit request =>
      Future(Ok("Welcome"))
}
```

and

```
object OAuth2Action extends OAuth2Provider{

    def apply(f: Request[AnyContent]  => Future[Result]): Action[AnyContent] = {
      Action.async { implicit request =>
        authorize(new OauthDataHandler()) { authInfo =>
          f(request)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

But, and here is where my lack of scala syntax appears in scene, I want to keep a reference of my `authInfo` object to be used inside the `index` function (because I need some user information there). Is there any way to do this?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:** Solution based on @johanandren answer, I realized that I couldn't send this data through Actions so I used the ActionBuilder to authenticate:

```
case class AuthenticatedRequest[A](user: User, request: Request[A]) extends WrappedRequest(request)

object Authenticated extends ActionBuilder[AuthenticatedRequest] with OAuth2Provider {

  def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Future[Result]) = {
    authenticate(block)(request)
  }

  def authenticate[A]( block: AuthenticatedRequest[A] => Future[Result])(implicit request: Request[A]) = {
    authorize(new OauthDataHandler()) { authInfo =>
      block(AuthenticatedRequest(authInfo.user, request))
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at action composition with action builders in the play docs, does exactly what you want:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaActionsComposition

Comment: Thank you for the info, finally I implemented my solution based on the documentation you provided to me. I'll edit my question with the current solution